# How to insert float values separated by a comma to Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hello to all once again :)

I have an ArrayList of Strings which contains various data. It is filled with numbers, decimal numbers, simple strings and so one(but all of them are stored as a Strings).

The problem is that since a while I have been storing those files only as Strings in Excel file using POI library with the following code:

```
 cell.setCellValue(listOfResults.get(iterationNumber));
```

Right now I have to face another problem. From time to time the results of this ArrayList are Float numbers with format *,* or Integers and, as you can see, floats numbers are separated by a comma i.e:

```
0
1
1,23
213,23899
```

For above data I have to set a cellType to NUMERIC(not as previously as general). So I was trying with this:

```
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0,00"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);
cell.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat(listOfResults.get(iteration)));
//after this I have a negative output with the following Exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2,26776"
```

And I know that the problem is connected with this comma value.
So please give me a hint in these two areas:

1.

```
HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0,00")
```

how to set it properly that it should be working for my example data ["0", "1", "1,23","21312,23999"] and so one

2.

```
cell.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat(listOfResults.get(iteration)))
```

How to properly parse a float with "," inside. I have tried with DecimalFormatSymbols but it doesn't work like I want with POI.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: do you want to save it with a comma?

Comment: Yes, I would like to save it with a comma.(excel file works with commas as a decimal format symbol)

Comment: maybe I dont got the question right but if you can be sure that your string values are always like you provided, just test it like this: `cell.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat(listOfResults.get(iteration).replace(",", ".")));`

Comment: Patrick, you're right, I know that it is possible. The problem is that in an Excel file my values, which are stored as 2,729123(comma) will be stored as 2.729123(dot). My goal is to save 2,729123(comma) in an Excel file with Numeric style of this particular cell.

Comment: I'm looking for adding multiple values for a cell, like a1 should have values (abc,def, ert). I'm uisng apache POI with java. Can you please help me with any suggestions for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just write the comma formatted floats into your excel file as a string. For that you do:

```
cell.setCellValue(listOfResults.get(iteration));
```

If you intern to use the cell value for further calculations as numeric values, then I think you only have to convert the string number to a float.

```
float value = Float.parseFloat(listOfResults.get(iteration).replace(",", "."));
cell.setCellValue(value);
```

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. The problem is that in my LocalZone in Excel Sheets we use commas instead of dots as a separator. So all of the dots in numbers have to be commas to make any further calculation.